# How to find double letters and replace them with triple letters?

Tags: regex, regex-group, backreference

I'm not using any particular coding language, simply a program with "find" and "replace" where both fields use Regex. For example, the phrase

```
too many professionals
```

would turn into

```
tooo many professsionals
```

I want to "find" any occurrences of double letters, which I know I can do with

```
(.)\1
```

What confuses me is the "take the doubled letter and triple it" bit. Is there any symbol in Regex that refers to "the current character" or something like that?

EDIT: Thank you all for your suggestions. It turns out that the "replace" field does not, in fact, use Regex, which IMO is bullcrap, and my question is now worthless.

Comment: Can you show us an example of an *input* you have and what *output* you are expecting?

Comment: The syntax to use when replacing with a capture group depends on the implementation. It may be `\1`, it may be `$1`, or maybe something else

Comment: what will be desired output in case of `tooo` ?

Comment: Another idea with taking into account that already triple letters shouldn't get a fourth attached: Replace [`(([A-Za-z])\2\2+)|(\w)\3` with `$1$3$3$3`](https://regex101.com/r/ZBn1f6/3)

Answer (score 3):

Your current pattern `(.)\1` which uses a backreference, is the on the right track.  Try this find and replace:

```
Find:    (.)\1
Replace: $1$1$1
```

### Demo

This approach matches any single letter followed by the same letter, and then replaces that pair by three of the same letter.

Answer (score 3):

[Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56419913/6553328)'s expression is incorrect, because `(.)` refers to any char, which we don't wish to replace that. We only wish to replace (English) letters or `[A-Za-z]`.

The correct way to do so might be an expression with an `i` flag:

```
([a-z])\1
```

or maybe an expression without `i` flag:

```
([A-Za-z])\1
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iq8MZG/1)

#### Test

```js
const regex = /([a-z])\1/gmi;
const str = `too many   professionals
would    turn into

tooo many professsionals`;
const subst = `$1$1$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Double to triple

Find  `(?m)(?:([a-zA-Z])(?!\1)|^)(([a-zA-Z])\3)(?!\3)`
Replace  `$1$2$3`

https://regex101.com/r/tOpl82/1

Explained

```
 (?m)                          # Multi-line mode     
 (?:
      ( [a-zA-Z] )                  # (1), Character behind
      (?! \1 )                      #      not a dup.
   |                              # or, 
      ^                             # BOL
 )
 (                             # (2 start)
      ( [a-zA-Z] )                  # (3), Character to dup check
      \3                            #      this is duped.
 )                             # (2 end)
 (?! \3 )                      # The dup can't be a triple
```

Comment: Only answer, that takes into account that already triple letters probably shouldn't get "quadled" and won't get matched =)

Answer (score 0):

It's almost part of your question :).

It also depends on the regex flavor that you are using.

E.g. for gnu sed, it's

```
$ echo 'ffoobarr' | sed -e 's/\(.\)\1/\1\1\1/g'
fffooobarrr
```

So, to tripple it, I just used `\1\1\1` as a replacement pattern.